# How To Get The Last Entry From MYSQL Database?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to get the last id which I entered to my database. Here is the code I use:

```
$test_query = "SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";

    if ( mysql_query($test_query) ) {
        echo 'OK!';
        $results = mysql_fetch_array($test_query);
        echo $results['id'];    
        print_r ($results);
    }
```

The only output I have is the 'OK!'.

What do i do wrong?

Comment: have you tried LAST_INSERT_ID()

Comment: Assuming `id`s are sequential, you could also do `SELECT MAX(id) FROM table;`.

Comment: @GeorgeBrighton no you can not because you're not using `TRANSACTIONS` and MySQL is multi-threaded. It two `INSERT`s happen close together you might get the wrong id. `LAST_INSERT_ID()` actually binds to your session so it's not bothered by multi-threading.

Comment: @Doge I was assuming the OP was not inserting into the table beforehand (there is no indication of that in the question), and simply wanted the highest `id` value.

Comment: @GeorgeBrighton Fair enough, but I think that's an unreasonable assumption to make. I was reacting to your assumption that ids are sequential, that assumption alone is not enough.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the output of `mysql_query` in `mysql_fetch_array`.

```
$res = mysql_query($test_query);
if ($res === false) {
    throw new Exception("query failed");
}
$row = mysql_fetch_array($res);
echo $row["id"];
```

Keep in mind that this reads only **one** row. If you want more use the `while` loop construction you can find here: http://php.net/mysql_fetch_array

---

If you just did an `INSERT` query use [`mysql_insert_id()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php) to fetch the id. This is a feature of MySQL. This works in conjunction with the `AUTO_INCREMENT` option.

---

Also, if this is a new site you're building use `mysqli_*` functions instead of `mysql_*`. The latter is deprecated.

Comment: i dont know how to use mysqli :( and it can get multiple queries :P

Answer (score 1):

You can use this if you have an auto-increment field in the table:

```
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```