# Get last entry in MYSQL database table using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I know this question has been asked multiple times on here but each one is a little different.

I have a table in my database with the columns `entry_id(INT- Auto_Increment)`, `user_id(INT)`, `firstname(VARCHAR)`, `lastname(VARCHAR)` and `comment(VARCHAR)`.

My script is pretty much a very basic timesheet I have tried creating, the `user_id`, `firstname` and `lastnames` are set when the user visits the script.  So what I need to do is check the **last** comment cell for that user to see if the comment is either  "in" or "out".

Whenever I try building my query and checking if the last comment in that users field is either in or out, I visit my script and it doesn't print the comment, what am I doing wrong?

```
$userid = $_SESSION['user_id'];

    $query = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT entry_id, user_id FROM timesheet WHERE user_id = '$userid' ORDER BY entry_id DESC LIMIT 1") or die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($mysqli));

    if(mysqli_num_rows($query)>0){

     while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($row);
        echo '</pre>';

        $clock = $row['comment'];

        echo $clock . ' Last entry';

    }
```

Couple of notes:

I AM connected to the database and get a simple query to work.
The userid session is set.
Prior to asking this question I looked at the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23065680/how-to-get-the-last-entry-from-mysql-database) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3411092/how-do-i-fetch-the-last-record-in-a-mysql-database-table-using-php).

Here is what `$row` is printing, notice how comment is empty although I know I have a value in the database.

```
Array
(
    [entry_id] => 4
    [user_id] => 3
    [comment] => 
)
```

Comment: Does the query provide the right result?

Comment: You're querying for entry_id and user_id but when you try to access the results, you're referencing comment as in `$row['comment']`. Where is that supposed to come from? The only keys in `$row` will be the fields you queried.

Comment: tip: always turn on error reporting! `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');`

Comment: Thanks Ghost, epic fail on that, turns out the include path was incorrect, cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just as you seen on comments, you trying to access an index which is not included with the one you queried that's why you dont get any results.

```
$userid = $_SESSION['user_id'];
$query = mysqli_query($mysqli, 
    "SELECT 
        entry_id, 
        user_id,

        comment <-- you're trying to access comments, but didn't include that column in the query

        FROM timesheet 

        WHERE user_id = '$userid' ORDER BY entry_id DESC LIMIT 1") 

or die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($mysqli));

if(mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0){

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {

        echo $row['comment'] . ' Last entry <br/>';
    }
}
```

If you've had turn on error reporting:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
```

You should have seen that undefined index `comment`.